# Time measurment in Linux kernel: how are clock_gettime, gettimeofday and getrusage related?

Tags: linux-kernel, c, timestamps, time, clock

I am trying to understand how time is measured by the Linux kernel. I tried to go through the kernel code, but I miss the big picture to understand the code that I'm reading, even if this [article](http://linuxmogeb.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-does-clockgettime-work.html) helped a lot. In particular, I would like to understand how the following functions are related:

- [clock_gettime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)
- [gettimeofday](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html)
- [getrusage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html)

**My questions are:**

- Do they depend on each other? Is `gettimeofday` implemented in terms of `clock_gettime` or vice-versa? Is `getrusage` implemented in terms of `clock_gettime` or vice-versa?
- If they depend on each other then, what is the most fundamental one (lower level)?
- If they do not depend on each other, is there an internal mechanism on which they all depend? A lower-level function of the kernel that they all call?
- If they do not depend on each other and there is no common underlying mechanism, what is the reason for that?

**Note:** links to [linux kernel code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17.9/source) are very welcome to help to understand how all that works.